# problem in xml parsing in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to post some data to url.I did googling and got some samples.I tried them out.But i did not got the response as required.

Below is the link which i tried

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Has anyone done this before.If yes can he help me

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: Please look below link more helpful to you. http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

Answer (score 1):

I create a class with all my information I need to send and serialize it to a xml file with simple xml. Then I send the entire XML.
But you can send fields only too:

```
static String CRLF = "\r\n";
static String twoHyphens = "--";
static String boundary = "*****mgd*****";
private DataOutputStream dataStream = null;

private void postData(){
    try{
            URL connectURL = new URL("http://example.com/upload.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            conn.connect();

            dataStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                //Send fields
            writeFormField("name", "bla");
                writeFormField("password", "bla");
                //Send a file
        File uploadFile = new File(SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR, "file.xml");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
            writeFileField("myFile", "somefilename.xml", "text/xml",fileInputStream);

            // final closing boundary line
            dataStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary +twoHyphens + CRLF);
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataStream.flush();
            dataStream.close();
            dataStream = null;

            boolean response = getResponse(conn);
            if(response)
            {
                finish();
            }

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
           // TODO
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
           // TODO
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO
        } 
}
private void writeFormField(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
    try {
        dataStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + CRLF);
        dataStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"" + fieldName + "\"" + CRLF);
        dataStream.writeBytes(CRLF);
        dataStream.writeBytes(fieldValue);
        dataStream.writeBytes(CRLF);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("writeFormField:got: " + e.getMessage());

    }
}

private void writeFileField(
        String fieldName,
        String fieldValue,
        String type,
        FileInputStream fis)
    {
        try
        {
            // opening boundary line
            dataStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + CRLF);
            dataStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;  name=\""
                                  + fieldName
                                  + "\";filename=\""
                                  + fieldValue
                                  + "\""
                                  + CRLF);
            dataStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + type +  CRLF);
            dataStream.writeBytes(CRLF);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            int bytesAvailable = fis.available();
            int maxBufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            int bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                dataStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fis.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // closing CRLF
            dataStream.writeBytes(CRLF);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "writeFormField: got: " +    e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
private boolean getResponse(HttpURLConnection conn)
{
    try {
        // try doing this in one read
        InputStream data = conn.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        //Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(data, "UTF-8");
        int c;
        while ((c = data.read()) != -1) sb.append((char) c);
        String document = sb.toString();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    return false;
}
```